# Task.WhenAll AggregateException not capturing TaskCancelledException\OperationCanceledException when other tasks faulting

Tags: c#, task, task-parallel-library, cancellation

When catching the `Task.WhenAll` `AggregateException` the `TaskCancelledException` is not available when other tasks are faulted. Running below code I get the following output:

```
TaskException
Caught in AggregateException
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException

TaskCanceledException
Caught in TaskCanceledException

TaskException-TaskCanceledException
Caught in AggregateException
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
```

In the last test `TaskCancelledException` is not thrown, nor is it in the `AggregateException`.

Is there a means to also have the `TaskCanceledException` in the `AggregateException`, or do I always have to check the tasks exception when other tasks have errors?

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Http;

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var task1 = Task.FromException(new ArgumentOutOfRangeException());
        var task2 = Task.FromCanceled(new CancellationToken(true));
        Test("TaskException", new[] { task1 });
        Test("TaskCanceledException", new[] { task2 });
        Test("TaskException-TaskCanceledException", new Task[] { task1, task2 });

        static async void Test(string title, Task[] tasks)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(title);
            var task = Task.WhenAll(tasks);
            try { await task; }            
            catch (TaskCanceledException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Caught in TaskCanceledException");
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Caught in AggregateException");
                if (task.Exception is not null)
                {
                    var t = task.Exception.Flatten();
                    foreach (var x in t.InnerExceptions)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(x.GetType());
                    }                   
                }
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `httpTest.SendAsync` I would suggest to create explicitly a canceled task with either `Task.FromException(new OperationCanceledException())` or `Task.FromCanceled(new CancellationToken(true))`. It's not clear, just by reading the question, what kind of "canceled" the `httpTest.SendAsync` task is.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Task.FromException(new OperationCanceledException()) is handled the same as the other Task.FromException.. , so its part of the AggregateException. But when Im using HttpClient and a timeout occurs as with above its not part of any AggregateException thrown from the continuation Task of WhenAll, rather its thrown directly and is caught in the first try\catch. I want to be able to catch both the OperationCancelled\TaskCancelled PLUS any other exception that would be thrown for the other tasks

Comment: How about `Task.FromCanceled(new CancellationToken(true))`? Have you tried that?

Comment: I've not said anything about the behavior of the tasks. I've just suggested to replace the `httpTest.SendAsync` in your example with a task created with either `Task.FromException` or `Task.FromCanceled`, and has similar behavior with the `httpTest.SendAsync`. As it stands now, your example is imbalanced. On one hand we see the `Task.FromException<int>(new ArgumentOutOfRangeException())`, which is straightforward and clear. On the other hand we see the `httpTest.SendAsync`, which is a mystery.

Comment: Ive updated the example now to use TaskFromCanceled, having same behaviour as httpclient timeout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior of the [`Task.WhenAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall) method is to return a [canceled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskstatus) `Task` in case some of the `tasks` are canceled, and a faulted `Task` in case some of the `tasks` are faulted. In case the `tasks` array contains both canceled and faulted tasks, the `Task.WhenAll` ignores the canceled tasks, and returns a faulted `Task` that contains the exceptions of the faulted tasks.

If you wonder why the `Task.WhenAll` behaves this way, you could think that a canceled task contains no exception. Its [`Exception`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.exception) property is `null`. The `TaskCanceledException` emerges only when you `await` a canceled task, and the only information that it conveys is the `CancellationToken` that caused the cancellation. Any textual information that was present in the original `OperationCanceledException`, is lost.

If you want to change the behavior of the `Task.WhenAll` so that it treats the canceled tasks as faulted, one idea is to pass the tasks through a converter that changes their completion status. Something like this:

```
public static Task CanceledToFaulted(Task task)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(task);
    return task.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        if (t.IsCanceled)
            return Task.FromException(new TaskCanceledException(t));

        // In any other case, propagate the task as is.
        return t;
    }, CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.DenyChildAttach |
        TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously,
        TaskScheduler.Default).Unwrap();
}
```

Usage example:

```
Task task = Task.WhenAll(tasks.Select(t => CanceledToFaulted(t)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to catch them independently, or just use `catch (Exception)` and filter the exceptions by type.

Be sure to throw any Exceptions that aren't handled so they do not end up getting buried.

Comment: Im catching independently as above, what I want to achieve is to catch both the httpTimeout plus the ArgumentOutOfRange that are being thrown from the WhenAll. It seems that the timout exception is never part of the AggregateException.

Comment: That is correct.  An AggregateException is a different type than ArgumentOutOfRange.  Just because AggregateException _can_ contain exceptions, it doesn't mean that it _will_ be thrown to contain them.  You have to catch AggregateException _and_ Exception.  Its very annoying but logically makes sense.